# Python Django Load Images based on Tab Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am using bootstrap with nav-tabs to hopefully select filtered images based on the tab clicked. I can do an AJAX call to the view that I created that filters out the images based on category and returns an `items.html` template file.

Is there a way to load the partial template without having to reload the entire page? Should I just do the AJAX call and it will update that partial view?

Comment: You can do the Ajax call to the view, and load whatever content you get back from the view into appropriate element using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make ajax calls to the view and return only the required content from the server and and on ajax **success** replace using **.html()** method.